# why am I not able to show the data I am fetching from graphcms using next.js?

Tags: next.js, graphql, graphcms

I am following a tutorial to create a blog using headless cms with nextjs .

Even though api calls are working but it is not being rendered on the localhost.
following is the code in index.js :

```
import Head from "next/head";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import { GraphQLClient, gql } from "graphql-request";
import BlogPost from "../components/BlogPost";

const graphcms = new GraphQLClient(
  "https://api-ap-south-1.graphcms.com/v2/cl4plwtca25zv01z4apa66xo8/master"
);

const query = gql`
  {
    posts {
      id
      title
      date
      slug
      content {
        html
      }
      author {
        name
        picture {
          url
        }
      }
      coverImage {
        url
      }
    }
  }
`;
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { posts } = await graphcms.request(query);

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
}
export default function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        {posts.map((post) => {
          <BlogPost
            title={post.title}
            author={post.author}
            slug={post.slug}
            coverImage={post.coverImage}
            date={post.date}
          />;
        })}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

following is the code in BlogPost.js:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "../styles/BlogPost.module.css";
export default function BlogPost({ title, author, coverImage, date, slug }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.card}>
      <Link href={`/posts/&{slug}`}>
        <div className={styles.imgContainer}>
          <img src={coverImage.url} alt=" " />
        </div>
      </Link>
      <div className={styles.text}>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <div className={styles.details}>
          <div style={style.author}>
            <img src={author.picture.url} alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

with the above code it is expected to show everything that is on graphcms but I am only getting a blank screen. Please find the problem here!

Comment: Could You provide link to the repo Please ?

Comment: link is not provided by the tutorial creator, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning anything in your `.map` (Assuming you really are getting data)

```js
{posts.map((post) => {
          return <BlogPost  <---- notice the `return` keyword
            title={post.title}
            author={post.author}
            slug={post.slug}
            coverImage={post.coverImage}
            date={post.date}
          />;
        })}
```

Comment: now I am questioning my career choices